# how its possible to Assigning value of one property into another by using logical OR operator?

Tags: javascript, ios, nsdictionary

I need **ios** code for corresponding Javascript code

```
var readers = {
    publicAccess: false,
    ids: []
};

    readers.publicAccess = public_read || false; // a = b || c     this is the format .
    readers.ids = reads || [];

   //where public_read and reads are two property of another object.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: public_read || false will always be public_read

Comment: Actually what does "a = b || c" means? Im little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for `ternary operator`, something like this `for example`.

```
a = (b>c)?b:c
```